# Linking successful even when library not found, why?

Tags: gcc, g++, ld

The following linking succeeds even through libthrift is not found:

```
$ g++   --std=c++11 ../gen-cpp/SharedService.cpp ../gen-cpp/shared_types.cpp ../gen-cpp/tutorial_types.cpp  ../gen-cpp/Calculator.cpp ./client.cpp -lthrift
$ ldd ./a.out 
  linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffd35dfe000)
  libthrift-0.9.2.so => not found       <======================
  libstdc++.so.6 => /lib64/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f1c7cb7e000)
  libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007f1c7c87c000)
  libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f1c7c666000)
  libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f1c7c2a4000)
  libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f1c7c088000)
  /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f1c7ce90000)
```

Just curious why is the linking succeeding when libthrift is not found?  If the answer is because libthrift will be dynamically linked during runtime, I guess that kind of makes sense as I see the following error:

```
$ ./a.out 
./a.out: error while loading shared libraries: libthrift-0.9.2.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

If my above understanding is correct, when why is the following command failing when I link with lib:

```
$ g++   --std=c++11 ../gen-cpp/SharedService.cpp ../gen-cpp/shared_types.cpp ../gen-cpp/tutorial_types.cpp  ../gen-cpp/Calculator.cpp ./client.cpp -lfoo
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lfoo
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I was expecting since libthrift is not found, the linking would fail with similar error message as above.

Any insight would be appreciated.

Thank you,
Ahmed.